# QStreamData : How to detect disk is full with writeRawData

Tags: c++, qt

Following line :

```
qDebug() << "Result writeData : " << stream.writeRawData((const char *)&header, sizeof(header_t));
```

is always returning a positive value even if my disk is full.  Why?  I need to detect when writeRawData fail because of a full disk.

Because it seems to never fails, my file is being corrupted because writeRawData cannot write on full disk!

So question : How to detect the disk full problem with QStreamData (btw, status always return OK!)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the number of bytes written is what you asked for.

Apart from that, there's nothing much you can do there. The underlying OS/filesystem can "lie", i.e. say the write went through (saved in cache) but later on figure out it had no more room for extending that file. The error might not be reported to the application until the underlying file descriptor is closed or forced to sync.

Calling `flush()` and checking its result could help. If that's not enough, you'll probably need to handle at least the file open/close yourself with system-specific calls.